# Как правильно опубликовать json-файл на сайте, сделанном на Реакте?

Tags: reactjs, json, react-router, deeplink

Стоит задача сделать так, чтобы при заходе на сайт (на Реакте) с Андроида пользователю предлагалось перейти в приложение. Для этого наш андроид-разработчик дал json-файл, который надо разместить по пути *https://domain.name/.well-known/assetlinks.json*.
Как это сделать? Для доступа к чему-либо по какому-либо пути у нас используется хук useRoutes из библиотеки react-router-dom, который принимает массив объектов, где ключами является сам путь и конкретная страница (реакт-компонент). Как там вместо загрузки страницы расположить json-файл? Возможно, это надо вообще иначе делать?

Comment: По какому пути запускается само приложение?

Comment: Андроид-приложение? Ни по какому, оно скачиваемое, а не открывается в браузере. Или я не верно понял вопрос?

Comment: Сайт на Реакте... Это как понимать?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Решение оказалось элементарным, но потребовалось время чтобы дойти до него. useRoute принимает только React-компоненты, json-файл туда напрямую добавить нельзя.
Поэтому нужно было просто создать простенькую страницу, внутри которой и выводится нужный мне json, распарсенный через JSON.stringify(). Ну и продублировать нужный json файл в двух местах - внутри папки src, откуда он импортируется, и дополнительно в папке public.